# C#: Create Resource file with values having French characters

Tags: c#, character-encoding, resources, google-translate

In my C# console application, using google translate service I am programmatically trying to translate MyResources.resx file into MyResources.fr-CA.resx

Here is the code:

```
public static string TranslateText(string input, string languagePair)
{
       string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
       WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
       webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
       string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
       result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("<span title=\"") + "<span title=\"".Length);
       result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf(">") + 1);
       result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("</span>"));
       return result.Trim();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var resWriter = new ResourceWriter("Translations.resources");

   ResourceSet resourceSet = MyResources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
   foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
   {
       string resKey = entry.Key.ToString();
       string resValue = entry.Value.ToString();

       var result = TranslateText(resValue, "en|fr-CA");

       if (result != null)
       {
          resWriter.AddResource(resKey, System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(result));
       }
    }

    resWriter.Close();
}
```

Problem is that some french characters show up as "?" character in resulting Resources.fr-CA.resx file and that also, only if I use `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`, otherwise it shows characters for example like "d&#39"

So how can I programmatically insert French based values in a resource file correctly?

Comment: well, would you mind using https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-language-api-for-dotnet/ the Google Language API for this type of translations? With using this API, you let all encodind - decoding jobs from one language to another to this API. It's just an alternative, I'll also search for HtmlDecode characters for answer. But in my opinion, give it a try.

Comment: I used it and it is giving me following error: `GoogleAPIException: [error code:403]Please use Translate v2.`

Comment: Which version did you use? Here is a list of Google .NET APIs. https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-api-for-dotnet/downloads I recommend to use Google Translate API for .NET 0.3.1.

Comment: Here's another alternative (it needs google account) https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/translate/v2 this is the v2 version. You can also try this one, --if you face any problems with other google translate .dll's.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your webClient encoding type to decode French characters properly.

So this line:

```
webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Have to be like this:

```
webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

and your "result" variable (after calling TranslateText method) should be readable in French correctly.

Please try this way and inform me, it worked for me.
Regards.

Comment: Ok I will check it.